# Is a Docker virtual volume fast enough for MariaDB read / write operations?

Tags: docker, mariadb

I have a question regarding MariaDB and Docker. Is it wise to use the volume that is already provided with the official MariaDB-Docker-image? Or is it better to create a folder that is shared with the host for better performance? One of my colleagues was afraid that read / write operations could be too slow in the virtual volume.

In my opinion, read / write should be fast enough on that virtual volume as Docker only utilizes the Linux core system, right?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking if there is a performance difference between volumes and bind mounts.

The answer is there shouldn't be. Both types bypass the slow copy-on-write storage drivers and are stored directly on the host:

From [Performance best practices](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/#performance-best-practices):

> Use volumes for write-heavy workloads: Volumes provide the best and
>   most predictable performance for write-heavy workloads. This is
>   because they bypass the storage driver and do not incur any of the
>   potential overheads introduced by thin provisioning and copy-on-write...

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link! Very interesting!